# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() error

Tags: python-3.x

Could someone please help with this code error?

```py
def category(miles):
    if miles > 5 :
        return "Long Trip"
    elif ((miles > 3) & (miles < 5)) :
        return "Medium  Trip"
    else:
         return "Short Trip"

df["Trip"] = category(df["MILES*"])
```

on running this code error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: So, the comparison needs to be done on an element level. When you try to fetch the boolean value of an `array` or `series` obj, you use methods like `any` and `all`, so you can achieve what you need here, using a lambda function as - ```df["Trip"] = df["MILES"].apply(lambda x: category(x))```

Comment: Please format your code, this is unreadable